# How to correctly restore system from tar backup?

Tags: backup, tar

Ok, so I decided to make a backup of my ubuntu 13.04 system using tar. I was following guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR) and I made a backup of my ubuntu installation.

Now, what I don't understand, is how to restore from this backup. Should i just untar this file to newly created partition and repair grub? Because that didn't work.
By the way for grub repair I used [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).
The thing about restoration is not explained well in the guide in my opinion.

I also found some alternatives like clonezilla and remastersys which isn't supported anymore, alternative for that is relinux, but I really find this tar backup satisfying, just restoration is something still unexplained to me.

Can you please tell how to restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is untar the backup to a freshly formatted partition, and restore grub.  To restore grub, you want to chroot into the partition, and run `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` and set it to install grub to whichever drive you will be booting from.

```
sudo -s
for f in proc sys dev ; do mount --bind /$f /mnt/$f ; done
chroot /mnt
dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
for f in proc sys dev ; do umount /mnt/$f
exit
```

Comment: I installed new ubuntu, installed some stuff and changed some settings to see if it will be preserved.
And OK that pretty much worked :)
And I remember, that before I asked here, once I got a message when starting restored system the way I restored it now except different commands for grub repair (but it was similar because I got that menu where I can select drives etc), that UUID is changed and system was stuck on boot/ubuntu screen displaying that message... I checked it after I formatted partition and it was different. Now it went fine, but could this UUID cause some problems?

Comment: @Andrej, I couldn't quite follow what you said, but one of the reasons for using dpkg-reconfigure instead of boot-repair or manually doing grub-install is so that it learns the new UUID of the drive it is supposed to be installed to so it gets upgraded properly.

Comment: The thing that it learns new UUID of drive answers my question. 
English is not my first language, so is hard to use right sentences for me.
Thank you for your help. Your answer is enough for me.